# Data looping and inserting in to Database?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have an array of two rows i need to satisfy two condition and based on that condition i should insert the value into the database.

Am getting the values using this query and am comparing $record['QTY'] & $record['FILLED'],the condition should be satisfied by each row in the database and when the condition satisfies it should be inserted or not inserted

In this case how can check for each row and satisfy the condition

How do i check the loop?

```
<?php

    // Include confi.php
    include_once('config.php');

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        // Get data
        $employee_id = isset($_POST['EMPLOYEE_ID']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EMPLOYEE_ID']) : "";
        $mobile = isset($_POST['DRMOBILE']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DRMOBILE']) : "";
        $qty = isset($_POST['QTY']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['QTY']) : "";
        $createdon = isset($_POST['CREATEDON']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CREATEDON']) : "";
        $status = isset($_POST['STATUS']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['STATUS']) : "";


            $select="SELECT IFNULL(A.QTY,0)QTY,IFNULL(SUM(B.FILLED),0)FILLED,A.PHY_ID
                       FROM PHYSAMPLE A
                       LEFT JOIN FILLEDQTYS B ON A.DRMOBILE=B.DRMOBILE AND A.EMPLOYEE_ID=B.EMPLOYEE_ID AND A.PHY_ID=B.PHY_ID
                       WHERE A.DRMOBILE='$mobile' GROUP BY B.PHY_ID";
                $query=mysql_query($select);

                while($record=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        // print_r($record);

                    if($record['QTY'] < 0.7*($record['FILLED']) )
                    {
                        $json = array("status" => 2,"msg" => "Error In adding Data");
                    }else{
                        echo $sample="INSERT INTO `PHYSAMPLE` (EMPLOYEE_ID,DRMOBILE,QTY,CREATEDON) 
                        VALUES('$employee_id','$mobile','$qty','$createdon')";
                        $qry=mysql_query($sample);                
                    }
                }


    }else{
        $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
    }

    @mysql_close($conn);

    /* Output header */
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
    ?>
```

Sample array

```
Array
(
    [QTY] => 30
    [FILLED] => 27
    [PHY_ID] => 1
)
Array
(
    [QTY] => 20
    [FILLED] => 24
    [PHY_ID] => 2
)
```

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Yes but already major part of the project is done using mysql so we are continuing it @ADyson

Comment: Well ok but you should have a plan to migrate the whole project away from it very soon. Writing new parts using a new library would give you a head start and let you overcome any teething problems more easily IMO.

Comment: Yes we are doing that but for an emergency requirement we are doing this  can i have any suggestion for this question @ADyson

Comment: Well, as for your actual question, your intent is a little unclear. You fetch rows from the PHYSample table, and if a certain condition is met, then what? You're trying to insert more new rows into the same table. Is that right, or did you mean to update an existing row? And you've stated the requirement but not told us what your problem is. Just from looking at the code I can see that none of the variables $employee_id, $mobile, $qty, $createdon which you're trying to insert are actually defined anywhere. What happens when you run this? A blank row?An error? Or you have another problem first?

Comment: the case is if the filled quantity is equal to or  greater than 70% of the qty value only then new entry should be inserted into the table or else it should not be inserted into the table and this condition should be satisfied by each row @ADyson

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154783/discussion-between-sairam-duggi-and-adyson).

Comment: you say "it should be". So when you run the code currently, does that condition work correctly and detect when to insert the new rows, or does it not work as intended in some cases? It looks like it should work just from looking at the code and sample data but it would be useful to know what your testing has produced. And you haven't answered my question about the undefined variables. Please provide precise details a about the nature of your _problem_ instead of only stating your _aspiration_.

Comment: No need for a long discussion room chat, if you just provide the simple details I am asking for. Show some examples of data which did work, and some which did not according to your logic, and also please tell me about where you defined those variables (if you did) and what the outcome of the INSERT is (does it work as you want?)

Comment: Actually..."if the filled quantity is equal to or greater than 70% of the qty value". If I try to write that literally in code I would put `if ($record['FILLED'] >= (0.7 * $record['QTY']))`. I think perhaps your current logic is a bit backward. You're looking at 70% of filled-quantity instead of 70% of quantity. Try my version and see if the `if` statement works better. Then we'll see about the wrong-looking INSERT statement.

Comment: Yes It's working pretty good but when the float value comes then any issue in inserting the data  @ADyson

Comment: "pretty good". That implies "sometimes correct"? Or do you really mean "always correct"? And "any issue"...what issue is that? Describe the problem properly. Again please be _precise_ and _accurate_. Accuracy is the first skill a good programmer needs, both in writing code and describing situations. I realise you may be writing in a foreign language, which is a difficult thing to do, but that does not mean that you cannot give proper information. You can at least repeat any error messages given by the code. BTW you can check for exact SQL errors by using the mysql_error() function

Comment: To continue: Where exactly is this problem float value? In which field? What problem does it cause? Don't forget I cannot read your screen, or your mind. If you can't provide proper details I will not be able to help any further unfortunately.